# PHP Reference the current array / best way to set default options?

Tags: php, php-7

What is the best way to set defaults to some functions/objects via an array?

Ex:

```
$cl = new Obj([
    'a' => Conf::get('a'),
    'b' => Conf::get('b'),
    'c' => Conf::get('a') + Conf::get('b'),
    'd' => 'extra',
]);
```

Issue is, the **Conf::get('a') + Conf::get('b')** is sometimes a very long string, that:

- looks bad when you look at the code
- has to do some processing, sometimes heavy processing

I'm trying to avoid:

```
$defaults = [
    'a' => Conf::get('a'),
    'b' => Conf::get('b'),
    'c' => null,
    'd' => 'extra',
];
$defaults['c'] = $defaults['a'] + $defaults['b'];
$cl = new Obj($defaults);
```

So, I'm looking for something like:

```
$cl = new Obj([
    'a' => Conf::get('a'),
    'b' => Conf::get('b'),
    'c' => { this->a + this->b }, # << replace this somehow
    'd' => 'extra',
]);
```

- Conf::get('a') and Conf::get('b') only gets called once

I currently have (but not ideal):

```
$cl = new Obj(Util:defaults([
    'a' => Conf::get('a'),
    'b' => Conf::get('b'),
    ':c' => '[./a] + [./b]',
    'd' => 'extra',
]));
```

Where Util:defaults sets an array, then loops over it again looking for those tags, and using xpath like expressions populates the fields starting with **:** with an *eval*.

- It's sometimes much faster than calling those functions
- It's usually slower in most cases (if that's not needed, do the loops for nothing)
- It's overkill if I make it a standard and use it everywhere...

I could use your opinions on:

- way to reference the currently declaring array, if possible in php7+
- a better way to add these defaults, from server resource point of view, and mainly programmer point of view

Comment: Please tag your questions with relevant tags only - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
function getA() { return 5; }
function getB() { return 3; }

$x = [
    'a' => $a = getA(),
    'b' => $b = getB(),
    'c' => $a + $b
];

var_dump($x); // ['a' => 5, 'b' => 3, 'c' => 8]
```